# What is the base minimum version of node and npm required for gulp v4.0.2

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I recently updated gulp to version 4.0.2 in one of my projects and would like to update my README's installation instructions. One of the requirements is obviously `npm` and `node`. I would like to know what version of `npm` and `node` is required for gulp v4.0.2 to work, the minimum version required.

I tried looking for the answer in gulp's documentation but to no avail.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at Gulp's [package.json](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v4.0.2/package.json#L13-L15) there's an [`engines` entry](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#engines):

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10"
  },
```

So I'm going to guess they keep that up to date and the minimum version would be `>= 0.10`.

As for the `npm` version, do a search for `Node.js 0.10.0` [on this page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) and you'll find `1.2.14`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Quick Start](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start) in the official docs implies that it will at least work with Node v8.11.1 and npm 5.6.0.

Not certain if those are the minimum requirements, however.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, I would however like to know the minimum requirements and if there is a way to go about this for any package